# How do I remove outliers from a pandas DataFrame that has both numerical and non-numerical data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

***I have a dataframe (cgf) that looks as follows and I want to remove the outliers for only the numerical columns:***

```
    Product          object
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 180 entries, 0 to 179
Data columns (total 9 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------         --------------  -----   
 0   Product        180 non-null    object  
 1   Age            180 non-null    int64   
 2   Gender         180 non-null    object  
 3   Education      180 non-null    category
 4   MaritalStatus  180 non-null    object  
 5   Usage          180 non-null    int64   
 6   Fitness        180 non-null    category
 7   Income         180 non-null    int64   
 8   Miles          180 non-null    int64   
dtypes: category(2), int64(4), object(3)
```

***I tried several scripts using z-score and IQR methods, but none of them worked.  For example, here is a script for the z-score that didn't work***

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
z = np.abs(stats.zscore(cgf))   # get the z-score of every value with respect to their columns
print(z)
```

***I get this error***

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-2759aa3fbd60> in <module>
----> 1 z = np.abs(stats.zscore(cgf))   # get the z-score of every value with respect to their columns
      2 print(z)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in zscore(a, axis, ddof, nan_policy)
   2495         sstd = np.nanstd(a=a, axis=axis, ddof=ddof, keepdims=True)
   2496     else:
-> 2497         mns = a.mean(axis=axis, keepdims=True)
   2498         sstd = a.std(axis=axis, ddof=ddof, keepdims=True)
   2499 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
    160     ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
    161     if isinstance(ret, mu.ndarray):
--> 162         ret = um.true_divide(
    163                 ret, rcount, out=ret, casting='unsafe', subok=False)
    164         if is_float16_result and out is None:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

***Here is the IQR method I tried, but it also failed as follows:***

```
np.where((cgf < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (cgf > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR)))
```

***error message:***

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-bb3dfd2ce6c5> in <module>
----> 1 np.where((cgf < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (cgf > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR)))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in f(self, other)
    702 
    703         # See GH#4537 for discussion of scalar op behavior
--> 704         new_data = dispatch_to_series(self, other, op, axis=axis)
    705         return self._construct_result(new_data)
    706 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in dispatch_to_series(left, right, func, axis)
    273         #  _frame_arith_method_with_reindex
    274 
--> 275         bm = left._mgr.operate_blockwise(right._mgr, array_op)
    276         return type(left)(bm)
    277 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in operate_blockwise(self, other, array_op)
    362         Apply array_op blockwise with another (aligned) BlockManager.
    363         """
--> 364         return operate_blockwise(self, other, array_op)
    365 
    366     def apply(self: T, f, align_keys=None, **kwargs) -> T:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\ops.py in operate_blockwise(left, right, array_op)
     36             lvals, rvals = _get_same_shape_values(blk, rblk, left_ea, right_ea)
     37 
---> 38             res_values = array_op(lvals, rvals)
     39             if left_ea and not right_ea and hasattr(res_values, "reshape"):
     40                 res_values = res_values.reshape(1, -1)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in comparison_op(left, right, op)
    228     if should_extension_dispatch(lvalues, rvalues):
    229         # Call the method on lvalues
--> 230         res_values = op(lvalues, rvalues)
    231 
    232     elif is_scalar(rvalues) and isna(rvalues):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     63         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     64 
---> 65         return method(self, other)
     66 
     67     return new_method

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py in func(self, other)
     74         if not self.ordered:
     75             if opname in ["__lt__", "__gt__", "__le__", "__ge__"]:
---> 76                 raise TypeError(
     77                     "Unordered Categoricals can only compare equality or not"
     78                 )

TypeError: Unordered Categoricals can only compare equality or not
```

***How do I resolve some of these errors?  It appears the combination of categorical and numerical data in my df is causing a problem, but I am a newbie and I don't know how to fix it so that I can remove outliers***

Comment: Try giving the specific column name from which you want to remove the outlier from. You should not give the data frame fully.

Comment: I thought about that, but was wondering if I removed the outliers from only those numeric columns, would it completely remove the record from the whole dataset (all columns)?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you're dropping outliers in the 'Age' column, then the changes happened in this column will get reflected in the data frame. i.e., that entire row will be dropped.

[image]

Reference: [towardsdatascience](https://towardsdatascience.com/ways-to-detect-and-remove-the-outliers-404d16608dba)

Reference: [how-to-remove-outliers](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-remove-outliers-from-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python)

Comment: The problem is my original df (cgf) has character columns and your example seems to show a dataset with only numerical columns.  I've already successfully removed the outliers by creating a new df_no_outliers.  Now I need to take the df_no_outliers and join it back to the df_with_outliers.  How do I do that so that it joins on the row index and  excludes outliers from df_no_outliers?